# getting single cell from sqlite into textview

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to get single data cell from my DB into text view

this is the function i wrote it in my sqliteopenhelper class

```
public Cursor getMainData(){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select NAMEPPL from "+Table_name2,null);
return result;}
```

and this what i did it in the main activity class ,

its crashing once i lunch the app and giving me something related to buffer while I'm not using any buffers

is this the write way?

Thank you in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DB db;
Button addmed,addpl;
TextView PPLNAMERES;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PPLNAMERES = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PPLAGETXTVIEW);

    db = new DB(this);
    listView();
}

public void addmedView(View view){
    Intent ADDMEDVIEW = new Intent(this,ADDMEDCINEVIEW.class);
    startActivity(ADDMEDVIEW);

}
public void addpplview(View view){
    Intent ADDPPLVIEWS = new Intent(this,ADDPPLVIEW.class);
    startActivity(ADDPPLVIEWS);
}
 public void listView(){
Cursor res= db.getMainData();
if(res.getCount()==0){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
else{
    PPLNAMERES.setText(res.getString(0));

}}
```

Comment: Please post your error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `res.moveToFirst()` before getting date from cursor.

```
if(res.moveToFirst()){
     PPLNAMERES.setText(res.getString(0));
} else{
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     return;
}
```

`moveToFirst()` method will return false if the cursor is empty.

Comment: still crashing and giving me this message in logcat     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: @OWA Then your `TextView` is null. Test it with `if (PPLNAMERES == null) Toast.makeText (etc...)` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: still crashing dhaval                       public void listView(){

    Cursor res= db.getMainData();
    if(res.moveToFirst()){
        PPLNAMERES.setText(res.getString(0));
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

Comment: @OWA Does "activity_main" layout has TextView with id "PPLAGETXTVIEW"?

Comment: Dhaval i test it its showing null , what it the problem . is it something related cursor ?

Comment: @OWA It's related to PPLNAMERES TextView. It's null so NullPointerException.

Comment: HOLLLY S*** i made a mistake thank you soon much it been solve the ID of the text view was the problem  :S